# Function undefined variable error without use of global

Tags: php

Recently have been reviewing how classes work in PHP. I have stumbled across this code and I am trying to understand why WAMP is giving me notices as opposed to my host.

```
$settings['ip_forwarded_check'] = 1;

function get_ip()
{


    $ip = 0;

    if(!preg_match("#^(10|172\.16|192\.168)\.#", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    if($settings['ip_forwarded_check'])
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        {
            preg_match_all("#[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}#s", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], $addresses);
        }
        elseif(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']))
        {
            preg_match_all("#[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}#s", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'], $addresses);
        }

        if(is_array($addresses[0]))
        {
            foreach($addresses[0] as $key => $val)
            {
                if(!preg_match("#^(10|172\.16|192\.168)\.#", $val))
                {
                    $ip = $val;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(!$ip)
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
    }


    return $ip;
}
```

The errors I will get are:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: settings in
Notice: Undefined variable: addresses in
```

I can fix all the problems by adding a "global: $settings; global $addresses;" but I was wondering how to prevent this? I know many claim I should not use globals in functions and so that leads me to wonder the correct way to go about this. I would also like to know why one host will show me warnings/notices and the other does not? I do not have the notices turned off for my host.

Comment: It's because u didn't defined your variable and u using it before you give a value to it so u get an error, that means that variable don't exists ! And u using that variable outside your function. Try to change this `$settings['ip_forwarded_check'] = 1;` to `$settings = 1;` and put that 2 variables in function inside.

Comment: But if I added $settings = array() before $settings['ip_forwarded_check'] = 1, shouldn't it work as well? Also, the $addresses variable is pretty much forming inside the function, not much I can do about that. Do I really need to set it to = 0? Seems weird PHP would require me to do that. Only reason I ask is because my host's version of PHP doesn't seem to prompt me a warning.

Comment: Add a `error_reporting(1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` to your script where u read that piece of code and u will get an real error.

Comment: I tried your code and it works if i put `$settings['ip_forwarded_check']` inside a function. Post code where your `$settings` and `$addresses` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Both your problems stem from the fact that you are using uninitialized variables. If you write

```
$foo = "abc";
```

in your code, then, if `$foo` was not existent before, it will be created and initialized. However, if you do something like this:

```
$settings['ip_forwarded_check'] = 1;
```

then you try to refer an item of an associated array, which was never created. Let's create it:

```
$settings = array();
$settings['ip_forwarded_check'] = 1;
```

You will also need to initialize `$addresses`, but I do not know about your task enough to give you any advice about the way you should initialize it.

Error reporting is probably switched off on your server, which should be the reason you do not see the error messages there.